# Getting Wrong DateTime Format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have this:

```
var dateString = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
```

But dateString is 13.05.2011 instead of 13/05/2011. Can you help me?

Comment: This works on my computer; maybe its a localization problem?

Comment: Which culture are you expecting?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer of course it is.  And, karaxuna, using an overload of `date.ToString()` is more efficient than using an overload of `string.Format()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `DateTime.ToString` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead:

```
var dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The reason why `/` is replaced with `.` is that [`/` is a custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property of the
>   current or specified culture.

So either use `InvariantCulture` which uses `/` as date separator or - more appropriate - escape this format specifier by embedding it within `'`:

```
var dateString = date.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Why this is more appropriate? Because you can still apply the local culture, f.e. if you want to output the month names, but you force `/` as date separator anyway.

Comment: I think your solution is better then setting specific culture

Answer (score 5):

```
// date separator in german culture is "." (so "/" changes to ".")
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2012 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2012 16:05:07" - german (de-DE)
```

so you have to change Culture from German to English!

you can write :

```
date.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-EN"));
```

Comment: And you can learn how to change the culture [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
  var dateString = string.Format("{0:dd}/{0:MM}/{0:yyyy}", date);
```

Also check out Steve X's site for string formatting:
  http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force the date separator regardless of culture you can escape it, like this:

```
var dateString = string.Format(@"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}", date);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: You need either to escape the escape character (`"{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}"`) or use a verbatim string literal (`@"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}"`)

Answer (score 2):

Simply try

```
var dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: I would upvote this for suggesting ToString instead of string.Format, but you neglected to address the key localization issue.

Comment: TBH I only just noticed, that `ToString()` overload also takes `IFormatProvider`...you learn every day.

Comment: Isn't stackoverflow wonderful?  Now it's my turn to learn: What's TBH?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a date seperator problem. Use this;

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", date);
```

Check [`String Format DateTime`](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) and look at [`DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeperator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dateString = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Today, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```