# string to dateTime convention changes the format of the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

My code is like this

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 dt=  DateTime.ParseExact("14/09/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am expecting `dt` to have a format of dd/MM/yyyy but the output I am getting is in MM/dd/yyyy format.
This is the correct out put I am getting `9/14/2017 12:00:00 AM`.
 Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: A datetime has no format, question can be closed. If you want to convert it again to string use `dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Can't you use- `dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` As @TimSchmelter mentioned, `Datetime` object has no format. You decide the format only when displaying it somewhere.

Comment: if you post the way in which you display the date we can tell you what the problem ist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: 14 month doesn't exist so your output has to be `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier `DateTime` is stored as a 8 byte binary block, not as a MM/dd/yyyy string. It's only on a call to the object's `ToString()` method that the current culture's format is applied and the text generated.

Comment: @DiskJunky I never talked about how its stored. Im talking about how it appears while debugging.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier, fair point. In debugging, it'll use the development environment's regional settings

Comment: yes fair point. not always. but I think It does appear to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you expect the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"` you need to specify it when displaying the `DateTime`. To do so you can use this overload of the [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

A `DateTime` on it's own has no format. Only the string representation of it has one.

**EDIT:**

Important remark by [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter):

`/` is a custom format specifier which replaces all occurences with the local date-separator. You either have to esacape them by embedding them within `'` or use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725575/getting-wrong-datetime-format)

That means either use this:

```
string str_rep = dt.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

or:

```
string str_rep = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is not the same, `/` is a custom format specifier which replaces all occurences with the local date-separator. You either have to esacape them by embedding them within `'` or use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725575/getting-wrong-datetime-format

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for pointing out. I incorporated it into my answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter, good technical detail on the forward slashes but unlikely to cause an issue for the OP as they seem to be operating in an environment/culture where the format code "/" is actually the "/" itself. Good to be aware though

Comment: @DiskJunky: i don't see that he actually uses `/`, otherwise there was no need to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` what he did.

Comment: @DiskJunky: checked it, his city is Kerala so the culture is `ml-IN` and it indeed uses `/` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `dt` is a `DateTime`, not a `string`. Format concept *only* applies when you get their *textual* (aka `string`) representation. What you saw is *probably* what debbuger/ide shows you as a textual representation.

If you get a *specific* format of your `dt`, then you can use `.ToString()` method with `dd/MM/yyyy` format and a *proper* culture like `InvariantCulture`.

```
string myFormat = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For beginners, it is *really* important to understand the difference between what is a DateTime and what is their string representation.

Answer (score 0):

If `DateTime.ToString()` is resulting in an unexpected format, the likely case is that the current culture isn't being set. By default, the date format used is taken from the host machine. However, you can either specify it directly by setting the thread's `CurrentCulture` for the culture code you need, or you can set it in your application's configuration file. E.g., a web application's web.config can have a `globalization` section, like so;

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Alternatively, as already specified, you can set the format explicitly via a custom format string `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Comment: Better `ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")` if you want to see the slashes